# python stop recursion in a function

Tags: python, function, recursion, dictionary

I have this function that works kind of like a tree traversal, but goes through a dictionary instead. Every key in the dict has two items in a list, so the structure is similar to a binary tree. I'm trying to find a specific key, while starting at a given key and when I find the key I want to stop my function and return the depth at which I'm at. I search through the dict find the key, but my recursive function doesn't stop at the return statement.
My function:

```
def count(dict, key, depth):
    if key is not None:
        if key == 42:
            return depth
        return count(map, map[key][0], depth+1)
        return count(map, map[key][1], depth+1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple problems here. One is that you have `count` calling itself recursively twice, once on `map[key][0]` and once on `map[key][1]`. But if the first recursive call finds the key, then presumably you can skip making the other call, right? I suspect that you want something more like this:

```
if key == 42:
    return depth
found = count(map, map[key][0], depth+1)
if found:
    return found
return count(map, map[key][1], depth+1)
```

That brings up the other problem: is there any way for `count` to reach the end of the map and conclude that it hasn't found the key?  Are there any entries in the map which don't have valid keys in `map[x][0]` or `map[x][1]`?  I think that once you've addressed that problem, the other one will become clearer too.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is incorrect for what you want to accomplish. Consider that the second recursive call to `count` is never invoked. Additionally, what happens for the case that your target `key` of `42` is not in the dictionary. I imagine you want something closer to the following function:

```
def find_target_depth(dict, key, target, depth):
  if key is not None:
    if key == target:
      return (True, depth)
    found, found_depth = find_target_depth(dict, dict[key][0], target, depth+1)
    if found:
      return (found,found_depth)
    return find_target_depth(dict, dict[key][1], target, depth+1)
  return (False, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should check your indent of your last two `return`.